# Ringback ViciDial via SIP Gateway

Tags: vici

I am using the latest version of ViciDial for my inbound/outbound call center and Asterisk 13 for my SIPGW.  When placing calls from my Vici server, I have the ringback working for my agents on the initial call out through the SIP Gateway.  If and when the agent has to conference a call or place a caller on hold and dial another call, no ringback to the agent is heard on calls going out through the SIPGW.

I have modified the context of the trunk as follows:

```
[SIPGW]
type=friend
host=192.X.X.X
qualify=yes
context=from-internal
peercontext=from-internal
auth=plaintext
dtmfmode=rfc2833
notifyringing = yes
progressinband = yes
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Put 88 as dialprefix in campaign 3way conference prefix.

Then go to extensions.conf and edit the dialplan which starts with 88
according to your trunk dialplan and  put  options as  TtoR.